# AdMob Native Ad not showing in emulator

Tags: android, admob

Our Native Ad implementation of AdMob is working with physical devices but for some reason it is failing when running it in emulator. Other types of ads such as Interstitial and Banner works fine in emulator, only the Native ad is not working in emulator.

We are using test [units](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#demo_ad_units) from AdMob

```
2023-09-22 23:09:55.713  6627-6627  Ads                     com.sample.app           I  This request is sent from a test device.
2023-09-22 23:09:56.849  6627-7010  Ads                     com.sample.app           I  Ad failed to load : 0
2023-09-22 23:09:56.849  6627-7009  Ads                     com.sample.app           I  Ad failed to load : 0
2023-09-22 23:09:56.849  6627-7019  Ads                     com.sample.app           I  Ad failed to load : 0
2023-09-22 23:09:56.849  6627-7005  Ads                     com.sample.app           I  Ad failed to load : 0
2023-09-22 23:09:56.851  6627-7005  Ads                     com.sample.app           I  Ad failed to load : 0
```